# Change of coordinates and diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, coordinate-systems

In physics, we often use diffeomorphisms to change coordinates on a smooth manifold $(M,A)$. But, from what I've seen, "changing coordinate" simply corresponds to give our self another atlas $B$ wich is compatible with $A$. Then, if
\begin{align*}
    A &= \{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i\in I},\\
    B &= \{(V_i,\psi_i)\}_{i\in J},\\
\end{align*}
we locally have the following smooth change of coordinates:
\begin{equation}
    \psi_j\circ\phi^{-1}_i:\phi_i(U_i\cap V_j)\to\psi_j(U_i\cap V_j).
\end{equation}
Thus, the maps
\begin{equation}
    \psi^{-1}_j\circ\phi_i:U_i\cap V_j\to U_i\cap V_j
\end{equation}
are diffeomorphisms between $U_i\cap V_j$ and itself. Is that right?

But is it possible to create a **global** diffeomorphism from those?

This question is related to the fact that I don't really understand why GR is a gauge theory.

Comment: I do not know if you learned this definition of "change of coordinates", but to me, it is not as you said. A chart of $M^n$ is a pair $(U,\phi)$ with $U \subset M$ open and $\phi : U \to \phi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. A coordinate system (or parametrization) is the inverse of a chart: it is a pair $(f,V)$ with $f : V\subset \mathbb{R}^n \to f(V) \subset M$. We write $p=(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ if $p=f(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$. A change of charts is a transition between two compatible charts, and a change of coordinate systems will be a transition between two compatible parametrizations.

Comment: This basically follows from the fact that you can glue together locally smooth maps to a global smooth map. More precisely, if you have a smooth map on each chart and these maps agree on intersections, then there exists a unique smooth global map whose restriction to any chart agrees with the local maps. The “agree on intersections” part is important because this ensures the global map is well defined.

Comment: I think there's a distinction to be made between extrinsic and intrinsic transformations. An extrinsic transformation acts on the coordinate chart, leaving the manifold fixed, while and intrinsic transformation acts on the manifold, independently of coordinates. What you're describing is an extrinsic transformation, while the gauge degrees of freedom of Einstein's equations are (in my opinion) more easily described in terms of intrinsic transformations.

Comment: @Oiler I agree with you but in this case, I don't see why those smooth functions agree on intersections:  if $f_{ji}\equiv\psi^{-1}_j\circ\phi_i$ is a diffeomorphism from $U_i\cap V_j$ to itself, then on $U_i\cap V_j \cap U_{i'}\cap V_{j'}$ the diffeomorphisms $f_{ji}$ and $f_{j'i'}$ doesn't necessarily agree. Indeed, $$f_{ji}\circ f^{-1}_{j'i'} = \psi^{-1}_j\circ\phi_i\circ \phi^{-1}_{i'}\circ \psi_{j'}$$ is again a diffeo but it's not identity.

Comment: I havent seen in GR physics using of an atlas which contains more than one chart (apart from introductory material where a sphere is shown). I believe generally the problem of glueing things together is ignored in physics.

Comment: That was indeed my conclusion. But for some spacetimes, some coordinates are only defined in a specific (non-global) region, e.g. Scharzschild coordinates, foliations of Minkowski spacetime, ... But maybe this problem is ignored.